# PHP HTML Simple DOM extract attribute

Tags: php, extract, simple-html-dom

I have this html code :

```
<li class="ipsDataItem ipsDataItem_responsivePhoto ipsDataItem_unread  " data-rowID='79528'>
                <div class='ipsDataItem_icon ipsType_blendLinks'>
    <a href="https://www.nzbnewzfrance.ninja/profile/69-mcfly/" data-ipsHover data-ipsHover-target="https://www.nzbnewzfrance.ninja/profile/69-mcfly/?do=hovercard" class="ipsUserPhoto ipsUserPhoto_tiny" title="Aller sur le profil de McFly">
        <img src='https://www.nzbnewzfrance.ninja/uploads/monthly_2019_12/mcfly_avatart.thumb.gif.af84871aaa1d14550c54992f9249440a.gif' alt='McFly'>
    </a>
```

I'm looking to extract only "data-rowID" value, 79528. I made a lot of attempts like

```
foreach($html->find('li') as $f) {
   echo $f->getAttribute("data-rowID");
}
```

or

```
foreach($html->find('li[class=ipsDataItem ipsDataItem_responsivePhoto ipsDataItem_unread]') as $f) {
   echo $f->getAttribute("data-rowID");
}
```

but none is working. Where did I get it wrong ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the string into the parser via `str_get_html()`. The attribute name selector seems to be required to be lower case.

```php
$html = <<<'_HTML'
<li class="ipsDataItem ipsDataItem_responsivePhoto ipsDataItem_unread  " data-rowID='79528'>
                <li class='ipsDataItem_icon ipsType_blendLinks'>
    <a href="https://www.nzbnewzfrance.ninja/profile/69-mcfly/" data-ipsHover data-ipsHover-target="https://www.nzbnewzfrance.ninja/profile/69-mcfly/?do=hovercard" class="ipsUserPhoto ipsUserPhoto_tiny" title="Aller sur le profil de McFly">
        <img src='https://www.nzbnewzfrance.ninja/uploads/monthly_2019_12/mcfly_avatart.thumb.gif.af84871aaa1d14550c54992f9249440a.gif' alt='McFly'>
    </a>
_HTML;

$dom = str_get_html($html);
foreach($dom->find('li') as $li) {
    echo $li->getAttribute('data-rowid');
}
```

Prints out

```
79528
```